# How to retain Syntax Highlighting during text highlight

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

In most code editors, the text highlight does not remove the syntax colors.

For example:

- Visual Studio

[image: example Visual Studio]

- Sublime Text

[image: example Sublime Text]

I would like to simulate this function in the code editor I'm making in QT; however, the text highlight turns all of the text into a single color:

[image: dsd] vs
[image: dsad]

Would it be possible to retain the syntax highlighting during a text highlight?

---

FYI: I'm using a `QPlainTextEdit` and `QSyntaxHighlighter` to create the editor. I've tried changing the palette of the `QPlainTextEdit`, but I cannot seem to find a way to disable the `HighlightedText` effect.

---

EDIT:
Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using to add some context:

```
void MyHighlighter::highlightBlock(const QString& text) {
  // Sets characters 0 ~ 10 to be colored rgb(100, 200, 100)
  QTextCharFormat temp;
  temp.setForeground(QColor(100, 200, 100));
  setFormat(0, 10, temp);
}
```

Comment: show more code, how do you define style. I'm sure you can define different style of text when it is selected and you simply missed that.

Comment: @MarekR I'm simply using the `setFormat` function within an extended `QSyntaxHighlighter::highlightBlock`. I've added a small example to the original post. I've tried looking for something to modify the `QTextCharFormat` to make the highlight color the same, but no luck. (Also, thanks for the post edit. Was unaware you could embed images like that >.<)

Comment: I've checked how Qt Creator works. Sadly it has this issue, that selected text is in not colored. So it might be hard to do what you want.

Comment: @MarekR Ack, I see. Is there a specific place in the code I should look to find where the text re-color is done? Perhaps I could figure it out from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news! After revisiting this issue, I found the solution after playing around for a bit. Feel a little stupid not trying this sooner as it works perfectly.

On the `QPlainTextEdit` (or whichever widget applicable to the scenario), you simply need to set the `QPalette::HighlightedText` to `QBrush(Qt::NoBrush)`.

---

For example, to replicate the transparent highlight from Sublime Text, you would simply do:

```
auto palette = textEditWidget->palette();

// provide highlight color with low alpha
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(255, 255, 255, 30));

// set highlight text brush to "No Brush"
palette.setBrush(QPalette::HighlightedText, QBrush(Qt::NoBrush));

// apply to widget
textEditWidget->setPalette(palette);
```

---

*Result:*

[image: i did the thing. hurrah! ~]